# SQL Server 2008 and C# Paginating Stored Procedure from Outside

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, pagination

I have +100 stored procedures (lot of reports) without any pagination technique, I was reading a lot about how to do it but all of you guys suggests adding `@Page - @PageSize` parameters and `CTE ROW_NUMBER()` approach.

Like:

```
;WITH PageNumbers AS(
    SELECT Val,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Val) ID
    FROM    Table
)
SELECT *
FROM PageNumbers
WHERE ID  BETWEEN ((@Page - 1) * @PageSize + 1) AND (@Page * @PageSize)
```

But exists a way to paginate all my stored procedures globally? To avoid modify one by one, maybe on my C# data access code:

```
    public static DataTable getData(string sql)
    {
        string dbconnstr = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;

        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(dbconnstr))
        {
            c.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, c))
            {
                try
                {
                    a.Fill(t);
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    c.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return t;
    }

   //Calling example
   DataTable info = dbAccess.getData(String.Format("EXEC reportExample {0}, '{1}'", IdExample, anotherData));
```

Thank you!

Comment: This problem is typical when you put business layer logic in your data layer.

Comment: Do you suggest not to use stored procedures?

Comment: Since you want to do the paging **on the server**, to be beneficial, this means you have to do it **inside your stored procedures**, so there's really no way around modifying each and every stored procedure where you want to use paging. Only alternative would be to use a different approach, e.g. use Entity Framework and LINQ instead of "raw" ADO.NET and stored procedures.

Comment: Thank you, I used LINQ for all business logic but not for reports, because the SQL complexity of reports (joins, subqueries, groups by, etc) result very difficult to me to deal with LINQ and to mantain it. Maybe using a SP which paginate over the resultset of the real SP? Maybe this approach could be done if I use Table-Valued Functions instead SP?

Comment: Sorry, and on the other hand, If it is possible I prefer to have the pagination code separated to make it cleaner. Of course if isn't possible, isn't possible :)